# Find the algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Here are some web application session ID's for 10 continuous sessions. Can anyone tell me how to check the randomness or find the encryption algorithm

- xijivjs42kkc5vmfqsej43yd
- 4cg5hnqmnddbxayxr3y5nnbg
- rz0rwwzruixms0fffj2thmci
- nxtsdo121pbyexmr0mvkesp5
- rela0qaygo3fzffr2z3masij
- yxuglco2kmgbtobp5j4i3ftu
- r5cgsa1p1ij4c4hvhwftwibr
- fs3elzgmrvxsal3jhkcdwwtx
- dhbq5fa0xl2pmggoekbljaoa
- muq3vcwrjb5whoglawppo4fn

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic; perhaps http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ can help.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Any code?

Comment: I haven't tried any code

Comment: At first you need a lot of these IDs for any statistical analysis. A histogram, as mentioned below would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Make a histogram of the symbols. Then subtract the minimum value from the maximum. The result is a measure of entropy. There's probably better ways to do it, but this should give you an idea of how to measure the "randomness". :)